# How do you remove repeating events in reactive-banana

Tags: haskell, reactive-programming, frp, reactive-banana

In reactive-banana I've got an event stream that produces a series of numbers, some of which repeat several times in a row (I'm not concerned with all duplicates, just sequential duplicates). How can I modify that event stream to contain only non-sequential duplicates?

I tried using changes to convert it to a behavior thinking the behavior would only "change" when the event was a new number but instead the behavior triggers a change event every time a new input event is received.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that the `changes` function should *only* be used for binding to GUI toolkits and thelike, it should *not* be used for regular programming with events and behaviors.

A function that supresses duplicate event occurrences can be expressed in terms of the `mapAccum` and `filterJust` combinators as follows

```
skipEqual :: Eq a => Event t a -> Event t a
skipEqual = filterJust . fst . mapAccum Nothing . fmap f
    where
    f y (Just x) = if x == y then (Nothing,Just x) else (Just y,Just y)
    f y Nothing  = (Just y, Just y)

test = interpretModel skipEqual $ map (:[]) [1 :: Int,1,2,3,3,2]
```

Running `test` gives

```
*Main> test
[[1],[],[2],[3],[],[2]]
```

as desired.

In other words, you can simply imagine  `Event` as a list of occurrences and then apply your beloved "list" combinators to that.

Comment: Oh, why didn't I think of that?! I've removed the ugly implementation from my answer in favour of this one.

Comment: if you shouldn't use changes, how do you do anything meaningful with a behavior?

Comment: @Orclev: You can `apply` behaviors to events. The `<@>` and `<@` operators are used for that. Also, you can use mutual recursion between behaviors and events.

Answer (score 0):

Well, `changes` doesn't turn anything into a `Behavior`; it just lets you *observe* the changes of a `Behavior` in `NetworkDescription`, so that you can glue it to external frameworks. The [behaviour of `changes`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/reactive-banana/0.5.0.0/doc/html/Reactive-Banana-Frameworks.html#v%3achanges) is described as `changes (stepper x e)` ≡ `return (calm e)`, so round-tripping an event through `stepper` and `changes` will have no effect other than `calm` (which simply discards all simultaneous occurrences but the first).

It's useful to have a combinator to discard occurrences that don't change the value, and I think some other FRP frameworks have one built in. But you can write your own pretty easily, as Heinrich's answer shows.